# Time complexity of generate all subsets of size k algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I wrote a code for generating all subsets of size `k` algorithm and i don't know how to determine its time complexity. I know how to solve simple cases, but I am still trying to learn how to solve these harder cases. These were just a few of the example problems that I could not figure out. Any help would be much appreciated and would greatly help in my studies, Thank you!

```
def getKSubsets(set,k=0,counter=0,binary=[],list = []) :
    if len(binary) == 0:
        binary = [False for i in range(len(set))]
    if (k == 0):
        list.append([set[j] for j in range(len(binary)) if binary[j]])
        return list
    for i in range(counter,len(set)-k + 1) :
        binary[i] = True
        getKSubsets(set,k-1,i + 1,binary,list)
        binary[i] = False
    return list
```

Comment: hint: You have a conditional function, and you should calculate the complexity for all the possible conditions. (of the first one happens, if the second one happens if non of them happens)

Comment: Unrelated to your big-o-problems, using variable names that shadow builtins is a bad practice (the `list` parameter). You're also mutating a mutable keyword default, if k equals 0 and `list` is not provided. The default value is bound once when the function definition is evaluated, so those changes will persist between calls.

Comment: Hint 2: name f to getKSubsets number of operations for given arguments. So you could write f(a, b, c, d, e) = ..... + f(g,h,i,j,k). Where the dots are the number of operations of the if statements. That way you'll reduce the problem in "find a formula for f".

Comment: Assume you corrected mutable default bug. Are you sure you algo work?
 Any non-trivial examples of arguments/result? (Fails for the trivial: for any set and  k=0:  it returns None, while should be a set consisting of emptyset.)

Comment: None type return bug is fixed.

Comment: The number of subsets is n choose k. Thus follows that no matter which algorithm you are choosing, the complexity will always be even worse than exponential.

Comment: @maraca Really depends on `n` and `k` relationship.